# Why was my question on 'why didn't the Allies discuss the possibility of a homeland for the Jews in occupied Germany' closed?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on [why the Allies didn't discuss the possibility of a homeland for the Jews in occupied Germany as part of the war reparations for WWII.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66143/why-didnt-the-allies-discuss-creating-a-homeland-for-the-jews-in-germany-as-par)

> After all, Germany was split in half, with half being under the Western sphere and the other half as part of the sphere of the former Soviet Union.

This is territorial dismemberment and if they can envisage this, they could have equally envisaged some corner of Germany becoming a homeland for the Jews.

The extant reason as to why this question was closed down was that it was merely opinion. However, exactly this case was discussed in *Haaretz*, a daily liberal-left Israeli newspaper recently.

I'd also point out that there was a similar question that was upvoted 16 times and an answer was given that was based on well-founded scholarship.

This suggests that the reason for closing my question as 'personal opinion' was seruously ill-founded.

Thus, I would like my question to be reinstated

Comment: This is a "why" question, which is to say that it is likely to be deemed "subjective" and "opinion-based" and therefore likely to be closed. A better question for the site is a "Did" question, as in "Did the Allies discuss the possibility of a homeland for the Jews in occupied Germany as part of the war reparations for WWII?" That is easier to answer (yes or no). But in doing so, some answerers will give you an answer to "why."

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't one of the closers, and in fact didn't see the question while it was open, so while I can't say for sure, I can tell you what I'm independently seeing.

First off, this is effectively a Holocaust question, because one can't really separate how these events shook out from the Holocaust. We have a documented higher quality bar for Holocaust questions. They can't really be problematic in any way shape or form and expect to remain open.

The question contains what appear to be misleading and incorrect assertions with no references (paragraph 4). Not a good combo at all with a Holocaust question.

And lastly, this is a bit more fuzzy, but it looks like it might be an attempt to draw answerers into an argument, rather that a legit request for historical clarification. I think if the question were edited to not seem so single-mindedly focused on Germany as the alternate, it would seem more open to answers and less leading.

On a positive note, I think the last paragraph does a good job of pointing out that this is something other people are talking about. However, I think we have some users who balk at anything smelling of "alternate history", so they might not agree.

---

A bit of elaboration on my "fuzzy" point. If I had one thing to add to Mark's "Why did I downvote?" question list it would be the following (and I might even go do so):

"I have a great idea to fix WWII, and want to win an argument with Churchill about it. You play Churchill."

This is a question where the poster is chiefly motivated not by a desire to learn anything, but by a desire to convince others they have a great idea how things should have gone, and historical figures of the time really messed up by not implementing this great idea of theirs.

Comment: Paragraph 4 was supporting evidence. As I am talking about war reparations, this justifies the focus on Germany. I'm not trying to draw people into an argument. A reasonable answer might be that despite the colonial powers redrawing maps right aroynd the globe, they felt extremely reluctant to do so in the European homelands in behalf of a people who was still felt at the time not indigenous to Europe despite the length of time they lived in Europe and the horrors that they went through ...

Comment: After all, it was still the heyday of racial thinking which only began to be dismantled in the aftermath of WWII. Whilst I understand that questions discussing the holocaust have a higher bar I do not think I was in any way disrespectful of the Jewish experience. As I point out, exactly the same situation was discussed in a left-leaning liberal Israeli paper.

Comment: I don't agree with your fuzzy point. I'm not expecting my question to fix the Israeli-Palestine conflict but to inform it. After all, one would expect during the Oslo agreements, that there would have been discussion amongst the participants for not signing the agreement even if, as we know, the agreements were signed. It's being historically informed to understand the views portrayed.

Comment: Apparently Lord Moynes did propose to the Jewish leaders that a homeland be created in East Prussia. This was refused by the leadership because by then they were seeking Palestine as a homeland.